# Android service sleep when screen is off

Tags: android, android-service

In my application service I'm fetch server to get new message.

After found new message my serivce application must be screen on and start activity to display a new message.

In service I don't have problem to resolve data from server, but when screen is off that cause of sleeping service and after start activity, that could not screen on.

activity start by service:

```
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

        PowerManager powermanager =  ((PowerManager)getBaseContext ().getSystemService( Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        wakeLock=powermanager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
                        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TsmsScreenOn");

        wakeLock.acquire ( 10000 );
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        setContentView ( R.layout.service_view_dialog );
}
```

My summarized service:

```
public class ToobaPayamakService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    };

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
    }

    public int callRequestFromServer(){
            if (G.checkInternetConnection ()) {
                try {
                    Cursor c = db.getCursorFirstItemReceived ( username );
                    c.moveToFirst ();
                    if (c.moveToFirst ()) {
                        receive_lastID = c.getString ( c.getColumnIndex ( "lastId" ) );
                    }
                    c.close ();
                    unread = checkWebService ( Integer.valueOf ( receive_lastID ) );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
                Log.e ( "unread: ", unread + "" );
                if (unread != 0) {
                    G.config_username = username;
                    G.config_password = password;
                    try {
                        G.getRequestFromServerByService ( Long.parseLong ( receive_lastID ), unread, contentResolver );
                        result_count = unread;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
            }
        return result_count;
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- notifyTest */
    public void notifyTest ( int unread ) {
        Intent i = new Intent ();
        i.setClass ( this, ServiceDialog.class );
        i.putExtra ( "username", username );
        i.putExtra ( "password", password );
        i.putExtra ( "unread"  , counter );
        i.putExtra ( "notify"  , notify );

        i.setFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT );
        i.setFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        startActivity ( i );
    }
}
```

Comment: check my edited answer for more detail please :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you have to grab a wakelock in your service.

Comment: whats does mean ? i dont underestand me. using wakelock in service?

Comment: Yep, using wakelock in your service

Comment: i dont blive any change.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this flag to keep your screen ON -

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

One more solution using Wakelock -

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
```

Inside onCreate -

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "doneDimScreen");
```

Inside onPause -

```
wl.release();
```

Inside onResume -

```
wl.acquire();
```

you have to add this permission as well for the Wakelock to work -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

For more detail on Wakelock refer - [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

Cheers :)

Comment: dont work some times.only twice work. after screen off by hand or automaticaly scrren off after 30 second :(

Comment: and work correctly when phone is attached on charger

Comment: problem dont resolve :( when screen is off service dont work correctly